# Sharing session when displaying the same component several times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component (as A) that should load other component (as B) inside a Modal.

In the componentDidMount of B I have these api calls (nested) which both are failing:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ApiService.openProject(this.props.projectName).then(() => {
        ApiService.getConfigTables(this.props.config).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                    configTables: response
                }
            )
        })
    });
}
```

If I stop with break point on the server side when calling the first api call, then continue both calls pass.

In component A i have the Modal:

```
{ this.configuration !== null ?
            <ComposedModal
                open={this.state.openShowData}
                onClose={() => this.toggleShowDataModal(false)}
                height={500}
                className="some-class"
            >
            <ModalHeader title="" className="">

            </ModalHeader>

            <ModalBody>
                <B projectName={this.projectName} config={this.configuration}/>
            </ModalBody>
```

I realized that the issue happens when I have more than one component displayed in the same page (with the same session). If I have only one component of B displayed then it's fine.

I'm showing several component (from the same type B) in a grid... seems that i have issue with managing sessions!

If I have multiple components, then they all will share the same session?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not properly chaining them. Chain them like a normal promise.

try to chain them like this

```
ApiService.get(...)
  .then((response) => {
    return ApiService.get(...); // using response.data
  })
  .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                configTables: response
            }
        )
  });
```

instead of nesting them, execute the first `.then` of the first request and then return that promise so you'll have a `.then` for you second request.

Comment: Nope, the same :~

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) for both! But as I mentioned earlier, if I stop with debugger and go line by line it pass!!!

Comment: I realized that the issue is deeper than that, it happens when I have more than one component... I'm showing a component s  (from the same type B) in a grid... seems that i have issue with managing the sessions! If i'm in the same session and have multiple components, then they all will share the same session?!